# How can I ignore Unicode escape sequences in Javascript/C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET Core which displays routes on Google Maps using their API. One of the ways it does this is with encoded polyline data, which it gets from our backend server. The problem is that when I pull through a value like this:

```
{konItyiI??mLxJaRhPwY}C{[cUc\ua@qYw`@uYe_@{VgZqTwTiHfE_N~`@oOvg@iVtg@qVld@{Vv`@oV|_@cDbXtDz\jDr\~Hj[|GfXjDr[pLtZdItb@pIha@`BpQOdH??
```

Then Javascript throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence` and the map never displays. This is because there's a "\u" in the polyline data. It works fine with other polylines that don't contain this data.

Is there a way to ignore Unicode escape sequences using Javascript? Everything I've found so far only relates to making the strings HTML-safe, which isn't the object of the exercise here.

Update:

I wasn't able to use:
`var coords = "@Models.Polyline".replace("\\", "");`
because the exception was raised when the string was declared.

However, I *could* use:
`var coords = "@Models.Polyline.Replace("\\", "")";`
using the C# Replace() method instead of the JavaScript replace() method.

This means that the data won't cause an exception when JavaScript tries to parse it into a string literal because the offending backslashes have been removed before JS sees it.

This causes a problem, though. The polyline data which is left over is missing enough data from the original that the route displayed on the map is almost completely different, especially over small distances.

Comment: If you are asking how to pass a string from C#  to JavaScript such that escapes are ignored, escape the escapes with  HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()

Comment: @AlexK. According to Visual Studio, this HttpUtility namespace doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to reference system.web or copy/paste the source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,c0289ba7b2d459e5,references

Comment: How did you fix this? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

try following:

step 1:

// put the polyline data into string variable before you use it

string bfesc = "{konItyiI??mLxJaRhPwY}C{[cUc\ua@qYw`@uYe_@{VgZqTwTiHfE_N~`@oOvg@iVtg@qVld@{Vv`@oV|_@cDbXtDz\jDr\~Hj[|GfXjDr[pLtZdItb@pIha@`BpQOdH??"

Step 2: 
// remove \u

nestr = bfesc.replace("\\u", "");

Now use nestr

Hope it helps!! cheers :)